# Assign a database value to variable

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, variables

I am working with a database for an assignment and I am doing a check to see if there are any overdue movies. I was wondering if it was possible to get a value from a database table and assign it to a string variable. Here is my code

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="CheckoutPanel" Visible="false">
        <h4>Movies that are Checked Out</h4>
        <asp:GridView id="one_data2" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MovieID"
                    HeaderText="Movie ID"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SubscriberID"
                    HeaderText="Checked Out On"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DueDate"
                    HeaderText="Due On" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Above is the panel I want to get the info from.
Below is the code I made but doesn't quite work.

```
protected void DueMovies(Object src, EventArgs e)
    {
        get_connection();
        connection.Open();
        command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM checkout", connection);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        int movieId = one_data2.Rows["0"]["MovieID"].ToString();
        string subId = one_data2.Rows["1"]["SubscriberID"].ToString();
        string dueDate = one_data2.Rows["2"]["DueDate"].ToString();
        DateTime lateDate = Convert.ToDateTime(one_data2.Rows["2"]["DueDate"]);

        if(DateTime.Now >= lateDate)
        {
            string EmailMsg = "A late message has been sent to " + subId;
        }
        else
        {
            lblInfo.Text = "No movies are due soon";
        }
    }
```

The variables do not work as I get an error saying I cannot convert to string from int. I tried to set as int but that doesn't work as well. There are two duedate variables, but I was testing to see which one would work.

Comment: _" I was wondering if it was possible to get a value from a database table and assign it to a string variable"_ What a weird requirement ;-)

Comment: well debug to see what is coming out from your "Rows data". You'll understand the message then. plus i don't understand where does `one_data2`come from in the code above

Comment: Your method doesn't make much sense. You execute a command and retrieve the reader, but you don't use it

Comment: @JackHuynh when you get errors when running the code, first thing is to understand the error, 2nd this is to google the error for an explanation and example on how to correct it. I would learn the basics first as well as learn to debug your own code

Comment: Where do you close the connection. What is `one_data2`. Why is `dueDate` the same as `lateDate`. Why are you accessing different column of different rows that probably pertain to different vidoes checked out by different ppl at different times .... . this is sooo confusing.

Comment: What is one_data2, where is connection declared?

Comment: voting to close this as the OP has clearly not posted all relevant code and appears that they are looking for others to do their assignment for them, @JaackHuynh if you have an error, post all relevant code as it pertains to that error.. you code posted as is.. makes no sense you are using objects but do not show where they are declared..

Comment: This is too broad because OP doesn't seem to have read a single ADO.NET tutorial. (leaving aside the assign-string-to-int issue)

Comment: if you are getting 1 row back then why are you accessing each row by [0], [1], [2].. they should all  be one_data2.Rows["0"] then the appropriate field names

Comment: If your MovieID field is an integer, calling ToString() on it and then trying to assign it to an integer variable isn't going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along this line - supply your own methods to create the connection.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string someText;

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("..."))
    { 
        // autodisposing if no longer needed
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM checkout"))
        { 
            var msg = new List<string>(); // collects msg to avoid several updates to label
            // autodisposing ifnolonger needed
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                { 
                    // if rows present, read one by one until done
                    while(reader.NextResult())
                    { 
                        // process one row 
                        var movieId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["MovieId"]);
                        var subId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["SubscriberID"]);
                        var dueDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["DueDate"]);

                        // check due
                        if (DateTime.Now > dueDate)
                            msg.Add(SendLateMail(subId)); // send mail and store message
                    }

                    // make label text by joining all msg with newlines
                    someText = string.Join("\n", msg); 
                }
                else
                {
                    // no rows found, set label text
                    someText = "No movies due.";
                }
                // TODO: set your labels .Text
            }                 
        }
    } 
}

static string SendLateMail(int subId)
{
    // Todo: send mail 
    // create text to accumulate for label
    return $"Due Email send to {subId}";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code sample is not complete, but I was trying to see where in the code you are using Int to String conversion. Visual Studio should tell you the exact line the error is on. 
I suspect the error is on line:

```
int movieId = one_data2.Rows["0"]["MovieID"].ToString();
```

You can't reference the rows in the data reader - you have to open the data reader and start iterating thru them and access each rows columns.

I would recommend using Linq to SQL or Entity Framework to get the list of records into a anonymous class with a computed column:

```
var movies = (from m in ctx.checkouts
                      select new
                      {
                          MovieID = m.MovieID,
                          SubscriberID = m.SubscriberID,
                          DueDate = m.DueDate,
                          // Computed Column is line below
                          IsOverDue = (m.DueDate > DateTime.Now) ? "NO" : "YES"
                      }).ToList();
```

Then you can add an extra column to your grid and bind the movies list to your grid. Here's the new column to display the computed column:

```
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IsOverDue" HeaderText="IsOverDue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand, after taking a look to your HTML and code that you're using ASP.Net Web Forms, right? If this is the case then you should try to parse the content of the cells in your gridview to the data types of your variables. 
The [GridViewRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow(v=vs.110).aspx) has a collection of [TableCells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow.cells(v=vs.110).aspx) that can be acceded through the Cells property. The way to reference to the *one* row is your GridView is `one_data2.Rows["0"]` and a way to assing the values to your variables could be:

```
 int movieId; 
 int.tryParse(one_data2.Rows["0"].Cells["MovieID"].Text, out movieId);
 string subId = one_data2.Rows["0"]["SubscriberID"].Text;
 string dueDate = one_data2.Rows["0"]["DueDate"].Text;
 string yourStringFormat ="yyyy-MM-dd" // or whatever format your GridView has
 DateTime lateDate;
 DateTime.TryParseExact(yourStringFormat, pattern, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out lateDate);
```

Another way may be by accessing the row's dataItem but as you did not specify if your grid is databound.